# Why am I getting only the last appended data in this - using canvasjs

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

```
 $("#main-content").empty();
 $("#main-content").append(
    "<div class='tab-pane padding-bottom30 active fade in'>" +
    "<div id='chartContainer' style='height: 300px; width: 100%;'>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>"
);

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "theme2", //theme1
        title: {
            text: "Basic Column Chart - CanvasJS"              
        },
        animationEnabled: false, // change to true
        data: [{
            type: "column", // Change type to "bar", "splineArea", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
            dataPoints: [{ label: i,  y: i * 2  }]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
}
```

I'm using `canvasjs` to display my graph. I want to show all data in graph from `i = 0` to `4`.... but I am only getting last appended data. how can I resolve this?

Comment: @salniro: when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `chart.render();` is inside your `for` loop, as well as your chart `var` itself, so it's rendering every time and when the loop hits the end, you'll have only the last iteration of the chart (along with the last values for your `dataPoints`). Move your chart definition outside of this loop, you'll only need it for your `dataPoints`... so it seems. Try the following

```
var dataPoints = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {

    dataPoints.push({ 'label': i, 'y': (i * 2) })
}

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer', {
    theme: 'theme2',
    title: {
        text: 'Basic Column Chart - CanvasJS'
    },
    animationEnabled: false,
    data: [
        {
            type: 'column',
            dataPoints: dataPoints
        }
    ]
});

chart.render();
```

Comment: @Nitika I am glad this works for you. Please be sure to accept the answer so be can both gain a little rep